# Object Array length returns undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as displayed below in the console.

```
console.log(roles);

User {0: "AdminUser", 1: "AuthenticatedUser"}
```

Although it is an array I am unable to get the array length.

```
console.log(roles.length);

undefined
```

But if access the array using index, I am able to get the value as shown below.

```
console.log(roles[0]);

AdminUser
```

Comment: That's not an array, its a simple object

Comment: how have you created it?

Comment: If it's not an array, then how does console.log(roles[0]);
console.log(roles[1]); display the values?

Comment: That is an **object**. If you want to declare it as array use `var foo = ['AdminUser', 'AuthenticatedUser];`

Comment: @pietro909: The array is returned from a mBaas service.

Comment: Can someone answer with a code to loop the value instead of just downvoting? I am able to access the object via subscript. so how can I loop them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an Array, is clearly an Object.

The reason why you can access it using an Array-like notation is that JS supports the square brackets access notation.
Since you have numbers as keys, it can be a bit misleading.

Comment: If its not array, then how console.log(roles[0]); and console.log(roles[1]); works?

Comment: Because objects can also be accessed with that syntax

Comment: So how do I access them via loop if length is not available? Can u plz add code to your answer.

Comment: use keys Objecy.keys() and iterate indexes

Comment: as @Clive said, you are just accessing the object with the square brackets notation. By chance your indexes are number, so you thought it could be an array.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Pietro, I found the solutions via Google after knowing about Object.keys().

```
Object.keys(roles).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + roles[key]);
});
```

For the guys who down voted, it's a new thing I learnt today about Object.keys(). Thanks for your encouragement by down voting. :)